# Need missing steps in textbook's proof about the norm and trace on a field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let

- $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$;
- $L$ be an extension of $K$ of degree $n$; and
- $N$ be a normal closure of $L$.

There's a theorem that guarantees the existence of exactly $n$ distinct $K$-monomorphisms $\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n$ from $L$ into $N$.

With these definitions in place, my textbook<sup>1</sup> goes on as follows:

> For each element $x$ of $L$, we define the **norm** $\mathrm{N}_{L/K}(x)$ and the **trace** $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(x)$ by $$\mathrm{N}_{L/K}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \tau_i(x),$$ $$\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i(x).$$

Then the book proceeds to state and prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem 8.16**
>
> The mapping $\mathrm{N}_{L/K}$ is a group homomorphism from $(L^*, \cdot)$ into $(K^*, \cdot)$.  The mapping $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}$ is a non-zero group homomorphism from $(L, +)$ into $(K, +)$.

The proof begins by showing that $\mathrm{N}_{L/K}(xy) = \mathrm{N}_{L/K}(x) \mathrm{N}_{L/K}(y)$ and $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(x + y) = \mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(x) + \mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(y)$, which is straightforward, but then, out of the blue, it flatly asserts:

> thus $\mathrm{N}_{L/K}$ and $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}$ are (respectively) homomorphisms into $(L^*, \cdot)$ and $(L, +)$.

Huh???  The $\tau_i$ are maps $L \to N$, so I don't see how one can assert that $\prod_{i=1}^n \tau_i(x) \in L^*$ (when $x \in L^*$), and $\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i(x) \in L$ (when  $x \in L$).

Could someone please fill the missing steps in the argument?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> John M. Howie, *Fields and Galois theory*, p. 142.</sup>

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the proof should work aswell, if you replace $L$ by $N$